# Get MetaBox value inside WP Rest API

Tags: wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api, meta-boxes

I have a registered meta box:

```
    $meta_boxes[] = [
    'title'   => esc_html__( 'Background', 'background' ),
    'id'      => 'background',
    'context' => 'normal',
    'post_types' => array('post', 'page'),
    'fields'  => [
        [
            'type'             => 'image_advanced',
            'name'             => esc_html__( 'Background', 'background' ),
            'id'               => 'background',
            'max_file_uploads' => 1,
        ],
    ],
];
```

I am trying to get that `MetaBox` value like so:

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args );


$page = $query->post; // there is a post

$meta = get_post_meta($page->ID, 'background', true); // $page->ID is integer

return [
    'uri' => $uri,
    'ID' => $page->ID,
    'page' => $query->post,
    'meta' => $meta
];
```

, but the `$meta` is an integer like `2225`.
The post has this metabox populated.

If I try with the standard Rest API endpoint, I am getting the value:

```
.... post data
 "meta_box": {
    "background": [
        {
            "width": 150,
            "height": 150,
            "file": "2020/10/163593234-e1603902300928.jpg",
........
```

My question is how to get a post MetaBox value via Rest API with a custom endpoint, because, `get_post_meta`, returns (I guess) some relation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [wp_get_attachment_image_src](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/):

```
$meta = get_post_meta( $page->ID, 'background', true ); // $page->ID is integer

if( $meta ) {
    $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $meta );
}
```

And you can see `wp_get_attachment_image_src` returning value [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/#return).